# MySQL: Boolean fulltext, search for words that begin/end with x?

Tags: mysql, boolean, full-text-search

Is it possible to match against words that begin or end with the searchstring?

Example:

I want to find a column that contains the word "pineapple". I want to find that row by searching for "pine" or just "apple" if that's possible.

Can this be done?

Current code, if it helps:

```
SELECT id
FROM movies
WHERE MATCH (movies.movie_title)
AGAINST ('+word1 +word2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: yup - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Could you give me an example? Edit: I know it's possible using LIKE, and it seems to be possible with REGEXP as well, but how do i use it in a fulltext query? See TS, i updated with code.

Answer (score 0):

For your example:

```
select 'pineapple' regexp 'pine|apple';
```

For the more general case if you can use a prepared statement you can put whatever you want for the regexp string when the query is built. If there are multiple things to match against you could build a complex expression, or subselect against the results and loop, or self join. There are lots of ways to approach this.

Comment: That works, but it is not a fulltext search, is it? If my DB wasn't so big i would use it, but i'm afraid this would be terribly slow in the long run as the DB just keeps growing.

Comment: It will find any instance of the regexp in the selected string. You can limit it using other params in the regexp (start /end of string, # of instances, etc)